# How to display data in a tree structure basen on column values

Tags: php, mysql

I've a table structure like this :

[image]

And I want to display the data in the following format :

```
A
    One
    Two
    Three

A
    A1
        Four
        Five

A
    A1
        A2
            Six
            Seven

B
    Eight
    Nine
```

I'm using PHP with MySql and I'm not able to think how to query the db.

Comment: I think this will mainly be a PHP problem.  For the query, you can just select everything and order by the category columns.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you for your response. can you provide me a general idea how to achieve this

Comment: I gave you a query with which you can start.  I will delete once someone else posts a full answer.

Comment: Seriously, seriously consider amending your table design (not sure why TB hasn't mentioned this already)

Comment: @Strawberry I wasn't in that state of mind when I posted.  Anyway, MySQL is no place for prettifying a result set, that should happen in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can begin with the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY category_1,
         COALESCE(category_2, ''),
         COALESCE(category_3, '')
```